# How to send data from fragment to activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

In my application I have two fragments in an  activity.
In one of the fragments I have data, such as :

```
String name = "Transporter";
```

I want send this name to container activity.
How can I do it? Please help me.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: Make use of interface :)

Comment: check the answer from Amit Sharma

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fragment will be attached to the activity which you launch from.

Thus, you can create a callback method in your activity which can be called from fragment using the activity context object.

Please see the below code snippet :

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment{

       OnCallbackReceived mCallback;

// Implement this interface in your Activity.

public interface OnCallbackReceived {
    public void Update();
}
```

In your fragment :

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        mCallback = (OnCallbackReceived) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {

    }
}

    // You can Call the event from fragment as mentioned below
    // mCallback is the activity context. 
    mCallback.Update();
```

Activity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements YourFragment.OnCallbackReceived {

    // Implemented method.
    public override void Update() {
        // Write your logic here.
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are calling an activity from a fragment and you want to send data to Activity you can use intents like below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), YourActivity.class);
String name = "Transporter";
intent.putExtra("name", name);
startActivity(intent);
```

And in your activity you should get the data like this:

```
try {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I don't use startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an interface.

```
Like 

interface DataReciver
{

  void getData(String data);

}


public class MainActivity extends AppcompactActivity
{

 // On fragment load


oncreate
{
  DataReciver obj=new DataReciver()
  {
   @overide
   void getData(String data)
   {
      // Here is your data in data variable 

   }
  }


  frgamenttranstatiion.add(YOUR CONTAINER, new FRAGMENT1(obj));
}


}


Create a fragment with constructor

public class Fragment1
{


 Fragment1(DataReciver datareciver)
 {
   datareciver.getData("amit sharma");
 }
}
```

Comment: my friend I want send from fragment to activity, not activity to fragment

Comment: Check the code carefully this is to send data from fragment to activity

Check the custructor of fragment when i am call datareciver.getData("amit sharma");   this goes to activity obj which is activity

Answer (score 0):

Currently best approach(and my suggestion) is using `ViewModel`. you can find samples in android site. But I should says it is still beta version.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like

Create Method in activity like

```
public void doSomething(String abc)
{
  // do your stuff here
}
```

and access it from fragment

like

```
((HomeActivity)getActivity()).doSomething(string);
```