# Android - I want to call getText() form another activity or class

Tags: java, android

To complete Register should be three steps in different classes and method read all string from another activities .
When starting project i have some error!

class1 (RegisterActivity.java)

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

            Next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next);
            Fname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.fname);
            Lname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lname);

            Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    fname = Fname.getText().toString().trim();
                    lname = Lname.getText().toString().trim();

                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,RegisterStepTwoActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();

                }
            });

        }
    }
```

class2 (RegisterStepTwoActivity)

```
public class RegisterStepTwoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_step_two);

        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation,R.anim.animation2);

        Day = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_dates);
        Month = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_months);
        Year = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner_years);
        Male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.male);
        Female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.female);
        RG = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rg);
        Next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_s_two);

        Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                day = Day.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
                month = Month.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
                year = Year.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

                int id = RG.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                Male = (RadioButton)findViewById(id);
                Female = (RadioButton)findViewById(id);

                gender = ((RadioButton) findViewById(id)).getText().toString().trim();

                Male.getText();
                Female.getText();

                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterStepTwoActivity.this,RegisterStepThreeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Here , i want to call all there class3 (RegisterStepThreeActivity)

```
public class RegisterStepThreeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText E_mail , Password;
    Button Complete;
    String email , password;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_step_three);

        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation,R.anim.animation2);
        Complete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.complete);
        E_mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        Complete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                email = E_mail.getText().toString().trim();
                password = Password.getText().toString().trim();

                RegisterActivity reg = new RegisterActivity();
                RegisterStepTwoActivity regtwo = new RegisterStepTwoActivity();

                if (!regtwo.day.isEmpty() && !regtwo.month.isEmpty() && !regtwo.year.isEmpty() && !regtwo.gender.isEmpty() &&
                    !reg.fname.equals(reg.Fname) && !reg.lname.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {

                    registerUser(reg.fname, reg.lname, regtwo.day, regtwo.month, regtwo.year, regtwo.gender, email, password);

                }

                else {
                    Snackbar.make(v, "Please enter your datalist", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

method registerUser can't applied all String!
Error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.isEmpty()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: According to JAVA variable naming conventions a variable name should start with small letter.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/20169993/4238189

Comment: @young exactly when i want register , some string from another class can't applied to method registerUser(string.......) and EditText always null or empty !

Comment: You are trying to get text from another activity.

Comment: @young yes i want this Mr

Comment: For example you need to pass fName, lName from frist activity to the next activity and get it on the second activity from there you need to pass to the third one via intent.

Comment: @young just call string form another activity that's not work ?

Comment: No. Plz check how the activity communication happens in android.

Comment: I would suggest you to use 3 fragments for steps and an activity to host them, This allows you to reuse your code for profile edit, Use fragments to get the input from user and do the functionality part such as contact server to register the user.

Comment: Use Activity/fragment loosely coupled pattern (Interface) to pass values from fragment to activity

Comment: Tried this link?  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45429715/4116560

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under your intent declaration try putting this code

```
intent.putExtra("data", whatever you are trying to parse);
```

The when you want to retrieve that data on the next activity write

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String whatever=intent.getStringExtra("data");
```

Now you can use the String in whichever way you like.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Error code 
 RegisterActivity reg = new RegisterActivity();
 RegisterStepTwoActivity regtwo = new RegisterStepTwoActivity();
 if (!regtwo.day.isEmpty() ...) {
    registerUser(reg.fname, reg.lname, ...);
 }
```

If you want to send data from one activity to another activity then you can put data in a bundle and then pass it using putExtra() method. For more details check [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20170125/4238189)

**Suggestion**

Use fragment instead of using three different activity for the registration task. It would be easy for the transition.

Comment: If you want to read string form resource `getString(@StringRes int resId)` or  `context.getString(@StringRes int resId)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Bundle` in your code.

**RegisterActivity**

```
    // Register one
    fname = Fname.getText().toString().trim();
    lname = Lname.getText().toString().trim();

    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, RegisterStepTwoActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("fname", fname);
    bundle.putString("lname", lname);
    startActivity(intent, bundle);
    finish();
```

**RegisterStepTwoActivity**

```
    // get intent for Register one
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        String fname = bundle.getString("fname");
        String lname = bundle.getString("lname");

        day = Day.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        month = Month.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();
        year = Year.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

        int id = RG.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        Male = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
        Female = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);

        gender = ((RadioButton) findViewById(id)).getText().toString().trim();

        bundle.putString("fname", fname);
        bundle.putString("lname", lname);
        bundle.putString("day", day);
        bundle.putString("month", month);
        bundle.putString("year", year);
        bundle.putString("gender", gender);
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(RegisterStepTwoActivity.this, RegisterStepThreeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent2, bundle);
        finish();
    }
```

**RegisterStepThreeActivity**

```
    email = E_mail.getText().toString().trim();
    password = Password.getText().toString().trim();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {

        String fname = bundle.getString("fname");
        String lname = bundle.getString("lname");
        String day = bundle.getString("day");
        String month = bundle.getString("month");
        String year = bundle.getString("year");
        String gender = bundle.getString("gender");

        if (!fname.isEmpty() && !lname.isEmpty() && !day.isEmpty() && !month.isEmpty() &&
              !year.isEmpty() && !gender.isEmpty()&&!email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {

            registerUser(fname, lname, day, month, year, gender, email, password);

        }
    }
```

Comment: I think it's true way , but startActivity don't work in class2 !

Comment: Mr and how to setup as like public void registerUser(String....) {}
and then in registerUser pass params.put("ex", ex); (HashMap)

Comment: You cna use 

    public void registerUser(String fname...){
        HashMap<String,String> map = new new HashMap<>();
        map.putString("fname",fname);
        ---
    }

Comment: public void registerUser(String....){
    HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map,put("fname",fname);
}

Answer (score 0):

save value/values in shared preferences as :  `

```
editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME,fNAme).commit;
```

and retrieve it any anywhere you required as :

```
String username= mPreferenences.getString(KEY_USERNAME,"defValue");
```

repeat the same procedure for other value as well.

Hope,you got your answer